# Django filter by min value

Tags: django

Right now I have this:

```
status = request.GET.get('status')
persons = Person.objects.filter(vip_status= status)
```

How do I select all persons with `vip_status > status`? I tried this:

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(vip_status >  status)
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write like this:

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(vip_status__gt=status)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different filter lookup clauses:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

You want to use the **gt** for greater than, (or **gte** for greater than or equal to). The syntax is to add it after the field lookup with a double underscore:

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(vip_status__gt  status)
```